# Best way of configuring multiple spanning volumes

Tags: windows, raid

Perhaps this has been asked before, but if it is, it is buried deep.

I am looking on the best way configuring a spanning and extending volumes to mulitple disk on server. I have heard about RAID 5, and some people say that RAID 5 is a risky way to protect data, but then some say that RAID 6 is useless. I plan on RAID 10, but I still not sure about the "0" things. Then there is a plain spanned volume, that I can do with mirroring.

I am asking for advise, on how the best way to protect data without sacrificing much? The recoverability and extendability is a must. I have multiple machines running near realtime mirror on this volume in remote location, but I want a reliable, but fast and cheap solution to recover when something happens to this server without depending on off-site backup. My goal is to minimize disruption in case of hard drive failure. I also need to extend the volume when I install new hard drive.

So... which route should I take best for my approach? Span-Mirror, RAID 10, RAID 5, RAID 6 or is there any other option? What are advantages and disadvantages of each method?

The files being stored are mostly pictures, spreadsheets, documents, presentations, and such. Not big files. Small, and numerous.

Thank you

Comment: How many drives do you currently have and what type of drives? How many users need to access these files simultaneously? Or is it just for home usage?

Comment: No. It is for a company. 1 SSD and 4 HDD. Users are about 50 users. Not much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, I would recommend you to stick to **RAID10 for HDD** and **RAID5 for SSD**. These approaches are a good compromise between performance and redundancy and are common industry standards nowadays. Keep in mind that RAID is not a backup which means no matter of chosen RAID type you still NEED to backup your data elsewhere.

For more information on RAID types here is a great article on this matter: https://www.starwindsoftware.com/blog/raid-the-love-hate-relationship-but-for-how-long-will-it-last

The option of adding drives to existing RAID array and expanding it on the fly depends not on the RAID type but on your RAID controller and his ability to provide those features.